# react-spinners no funciona | nextjs

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, frontend

La situation es simple, tengo un spinner que quiero que se muestre cuado el valor loader es true, pero no funciona, si pongo una palabra como 'ok' esta si aparece y desaparece.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/ClipLoader";

export default function Home() {
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false)

  const handleCLick = () => {
    setLoader(!loader)
  }
  
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={handleCLick}>click</button>
      {
        loader && <ClipLoader></ClipLoader>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

edit:si hago el build y ejecuto con `npm run start` el loader si aparece, el problema esta en la fase de desarrollo usando `npm run dev`

Comment: No le veo el problema a tu código, lo probé en [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-worker-s9zf9?file=/src/App.js) y funciona perfecto. Podrías ir haciéndole `console.log()` al estado `loader` y asegurarte de que está cambiando correctamente a `true` al hacerle el clic.

Comment: si, y en produccion tambien funciona, el tema es que no puedo verlo en modo desarollo para ver como va quedando el dise~no